# Run something 5 seconds before Cloud Function times out

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

If I have a Google Cloud function, and I deploy it with a maximum timeout (of lets say `540s`), how can I before timing it out run something? For instance, 5 seconds before timing out, I would like to run a custom line? For example:

```
def run_something(data, context):
    print('Function running...')
    time.sleep(600)

    if time_left <= 5_seconds: 
       print("Function is about to time out in 5 seconds")
```

Comment: Can you please share your sanitized Cloud Function code where the tasks times out? Or explain the scenario in order to provide workarounds to catch the exception or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track the requests which time out for further investigation, you can filter the timeouts requests for your Cloud Function in **Stackdriver Logging**.

Note that timeouts are not reported as an error in Stackdriver however you can set up a filter the timeout log entries. From the Google Cloud Platform Console, go to the *Stackdriver Logging* and build a filter as following to get the requests which timed out:

```
resource.type="cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name="[YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME_HERE]"
"finished with status: 'timeout'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time.sleep(535)
print('do something')
```

Curious what the purpose of waiting is though?  Surely there's a better way to handle this because you pay for the length of time between receiving a request and sending a response.

You could also calculate how long it's been running to allow it to do work like this:

```
start_time = time.time()
print('do_work')

while time.time() - start_time > 535:
  time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: The purpose of this thought is because I have 1% of my task executions timing out. I would like to move these executions to another status (internal composer) that explicitly states "timed_out" so I can investigate in detail. Now as it just times out, I have no way of catching this exception.

Comment: Got it.  The second option is better because it allows starts a time marker when the execution begins.  You can check time periodically by comparing the difference, and handle accordingly.  If you have repetitive code in your function (i.e. iterating over a series of APIs calls) you can save state to a database and allow a new function execution to pick up where this one left off.

Comment: Hmm not sure that I get it. Here you do a while loop. What if you have a function inside, and you want the monitor the overall session duration?

Comment: It's hard to provide a good suggestion if you don't start with code that is closer to what you actually need to do.  My suggestion achieves your objective.  Cloud Functions weren't designed for long running processes.  You are trying to max out the run time when you should be minimizing it.  The best design is one that breaks your work up into small tasks and if you need to repeat things then save state to a persistent storage (i.e. redis, cloud storage, firestore, etc) so that subsequent executions pick up where the last one left off.